# setting subclass inside an if statement

Tags: objective-c, subclass

I have two subclasses SubClassA and SubClassB, both of these are subclasses of ClassA, which has a property called someProperty.
I want to decide inside of an if-statement which of these subclasses to use, and later on be able to use this object.

```
if(conditionA){
    SubClassA *myObject;
}
else{
    SubClassB *myObject;
}    

myObject.someProperty=someValue;
```

This does not work since I can't use myObject outside of the if-else-statement. How can I solve this problem? Is it possible first create a parent object and then change it to be belong to a subclass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a variable in the enclosing scope of the parent class's type. You can assign subclasses to variables of their parent class type without a cast.

```
SuperClass *myObject = nil;
if (a) {
    myObject = [[SubClassA alloc] init...];
} else {
    myObject = [[SubClassB alloc] init...];
}
myObject.someProperty=SomeValue;
```

Assuming, of course, that someProperty is declared on the superclass. Otherwise I think this code probably needs to be reconsidered.

Comment: And one can later use `[myObject isKindOfClass[SubClassA class]]` to test the object type, and then cast to `(SubClassA*)` if necessary to invoke methods only supported by SubClassA.